# How do I kill this tomcat process in Terminal?

Tags: java, linux, unix, tomcat, terminal

Using `ps -ef | grep tomcat` I found a tomcat server that is running. I tried `kill -9 {id}` but it returns "No such process." What am I doing wrong?

Here's an example:

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro:test-parent tom.maxwell$ ps -ef | grep tomcat
2043706342 39707 39695   0  3:40PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep tomcat
Admins-MacBook-Pro:test-parent tom.maxwell$ kill -9 39707
-bash: kill: (39707) - No such process
```

Comment: That's actually grep searching for tomcat.

Answer (score 178):

There is no need to know Tomcat's pid (process ID) to kill it. You can use the following command to kill Tomcat:

```
pkill -9 -f tomcat
```

Comment: short and crispy. BTW I have 2 tomcat one is tomcat 7 and another one is tomcat 5 process so it was killing 2. I used slightly different variant `pkill -9 -f /tomcat7path`   and `pkill -9 -f /tomcat5path` so that I can kill one at a time. it was very easy to configure as `alias` as it doesnt have backticks and single quotes in the command .... Very good answer

Comment: Note that "-f" matches all command-line arguments, not just the process name so even if the process name is "java", it will still match. "pgrep -f tomcat" shows what will match.

Comment: "pkill -9 -f catalina" also works for me. My eclipse "java" process also has "tomcat" in the "ps -ef" but for some reason "pgrep -f tomcat" does not match it.

Answer (score 22):

> ps -ef | grep tomcat | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

https://gist.github.com/nrshrivatsan/1d2ea4fcdcb9d1857076

**Part 1**

> ps -ef | grep  tomcat  => Get all processes with tomcat grep

**Part 2**

Once we have process details, we pipe it into the part 2 of the script

> awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 => Get the second column [Process id] and kill them with -9 option

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 20):

Tomcat is not running.  Your search is showing you the grep process, which is searching for tomcat.  Of course, by the time you see that output, grep is no longer running, so the pid is no longer valid.

Comment: Next time use ps -ef | grep [t]omcat

Answer (score 16):

just type the below command in terminal

```
ps -ef |grep 'catalina'
```

copy the value of process id  then type the following command and paste process id

```
 kill -9 processid
```

Comment: this is the first one that worked for me on Linux Mint 18.3, the selected answer had no effect.

Comment: This worked for me when tomcat is run via eclipse and the process name is "java". My other "java" process is eclipse. See related answer with "org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap".

Answer (score 12):

As others already noted, you have seen the grep process. If you want to restrict the output to tomcat itself, you have two alternatives

- wrap the first searched character in a character class

  ```
  ps -ef | grep '[t]omcat'
  ```

  This searches for tomcat too, but misses the `grep [t]omcat` entry, because it isn't matched by `[t]omcat`.
- use a custom output format with ps

  ```
  ps -e -o pid,comm | grep tomcat
  ```

  This shows only the pid and the name of the process without the process arguments. So, grep is listed as `grep` and not as `grep tomcat`.

Answer (score 6):

```
ps -Af | grep "tomcat" | grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: This is the best answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In `tomcat/bin/catalina.sh`

add the following line after just after the comment section ends:

```
CATALINA_PID=someFile.txt
```

then, to kill a running instance of Tomcat, you can use:

```
kill -9 `cat someFile.txt`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -ef
```

will list all your currently running processes

```
| grep tomcat
```

will pass the output to `grep` and look for instances of tomcat.  Since the `grep` is a process itself, it is returned from your command.  However, your output shows no processes of Tomcat running.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Step 1 :      echo `ps aux | grep org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'`

This above command return "process_id"

Step 2:       kill -9 process_id
// This process_id same as Step 1: output

Answer (score 1):

To kill a process by name I use the following

`ps aux | grep "search-term" | grep -v grep | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2 | xargs kill -9`

The `tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2` is same as `awk '{print $2}'`. `tr` supressess the tab spaces into single space and `cut` is provided with `<SPACE>` as the delimiter and the second column is requested. The second column in the `ps aux` output is the process id.

Answer (score 1):

this works very well (find tomcat processes and kill them forcibly)

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: This returned 2 pids for me which one will it kill out of them?

Comment: It is better to use `ps -ef | grep -i 'tomcat' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9` to give you pids only of tomcat processes, excluding grep process. @Alpha, I suppose the second pid you have got was the pid of grep process itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had to terminate activeMQ java process among many java processes on the server, and this one is started by the specific user (username is activemq).
So good way of separating may be to start a process by a specific user :

```
ps -ef | grep "activemq" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Aurand to said, tomcat is not running.  you can use the

`ps -ef |grep java | grep tomcat` command to ignore the `ps` programs.

worked for me in the shell scripte files.

Answer (score 0):

```
kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep 8084 | awk 'NR==2{print $2}')
```

NR is for the number of records in the input file.
`awk` can find or replaces text

Answer (score 0):

For mac users,

This is the only solution working for me.

```
sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:8080`
```

Note: replace **8080** with your port number