# Tomcat server shutdown.sh: no permission

Tags: tomcat, permissions, shutdown

I am trying to run the shutdown.sh file to stop tomcat server but I always get this error.

[image: Error Message]

I have tried all kind of chmods command but nothing works:

[image: Permission rights on shutdown.sh file]

I really don't undertand where doest that come from.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sudo shutdown.sh`

If you are unable to stop it you can always kill the process, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29405856/2601113) if you need help.